# Javascript VSCode function definition broken with module exports

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a Chrome extension and have a set of js files imported in the extension's popup in `<script defer src="../utils/X.js"></script>` tags.

The folder structure looks like

```
src/
  utils/
    parser.js
    functions.js
    other.js
  popup/
    popup.js
    popup.html
```

`popup.js` uses functions from files in `utils/` and the files in `utils/` use each other's functions.

All was going well and I could navigate to function definitions with `cmd+click`

As I integrated tests, and to be able to test my functions in a `node` environment (`mocha`) I added the following at the bottom of my util files:

```js
if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports != null) {
    module.exports = {
        log,
        ...
    };
}
```

And that breaks VSCode's ability to `Go to Definition`, not sure why or how to fix it.

For reference, here's my `jsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.js"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from VSCode's JS and TS language features relying on `module.exports = {...}` to determine whether a file should be treated as a script or a module. A workaround is therefore to trick it with the following:

```
if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports != null) {
    var dummyModule = module;
    dummyModule.exports = {
        log,
        ...
    };
}
```